# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'dependenciascheckbox' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring

hola tengo  un problema me sale este error pero he revisado y no se en si que es?

```html
<form:form method="get" commandName="dependenciascheckbox" class="form-horizontal">
  <a class="text-left" action="eliminar_dependencia.htm" /> "><span class="icon"><i class="icon-trash"></i></span></a>
  <c:forEach items="${depende}" var="dato">

    <td>
      <form:checkboxes items="true" path="isSelected" value="ON" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <c:out value="${dato.idDependencias}" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <c:out value="${dato.nomDependencia}" />
    </td>
    <td </td>

</c:forEach>
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "eliminar_dependencia.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView eliminar_dependencia( @ModelAttribute("dependenciascheckbox") Dependenciascheckbox d, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status, HttpServletRequest re, Model model ) throws IOException { 

  this.validardependependenciacheckbox.validate(d, result); 
  ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(); 
  if (result.hasErrors()) { 
    if (d.getIsSelected().equals(mav) == true) { 
      new MetodosHql().eliminarDatos(Integer.parseInt(re.getParameter("id")), new Dependenciascheckbox(d.getIsSelected(), d.getIdDependencias()));
      //System.err.println("id"+d.getIdDependencias()+"select"+d.getSelect()); 
      mav.setViewName("redirect:/admin_roles.htm"); return mav; 
    } 
  } 
  return mav; 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posiblemente tu problema venga de que estás mandando el formulario por `GET`.

Cuando lo envías de esta manera, lo que realmente estás haciendo es enviar los datos como parámetros en la url, por ejemplo:

`www.myurl.es/test?param1=value1`

Por lo que en el controlador de Spring deberías procesarlo con `@RequestParam`.

Dicho esto, esa no es la manera correcta de enviar el formulario, lo correcto sería hacerlo mediante `POST`:

`<form:form method="POST" commandName="dependenciascheckbox" class="form-horizontal">`

De esta manera, los datos del formulario se envían en el cuerpo de la request y puedes procesarlo con `@ModelAttribute` en el controlador.

En [esta](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) entrada puedes aprender un poco más acerca del verbo con el que enviar formularios.

Comment: si ese era el error me vine a dar cuenta leyendo dado que tengo muchos métodos y no me di cuenta gracias.